# Unknown column 'email_input' (PHP MySQLi Prepared Statement)

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using MySQLiIn the `WHERE` clause of my statement I am adding parameters on RHS:

Prepared statement:

`$sql = 'select * from emailstobeverified where email=email_input and verification_code=code_input;';`

And then I use `$stmt->prepare($sql);`

And I get a PHP error saying:

`Sql Error: Unknown column 'email_input' in 'where clause'`

(I thought that the LHS of the boolean expression counts as the column? )

the below query will work:

`$sql = 'insert into emailstobeverified (email) values (:email);';`

Here, I can use `:email` as a parameter, so I tried making `email_input` have a colon before it: `:email_input` and used that as the param. However I got a syntax error:

```
Sql Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':email_input and verification_code=:code_input' at line 1
```

What's the correct syntax for comparing the table column value to some param?

Comment: you are  trying to mix PDO and mysqi syntax here. Just keep to the same syntax. there is **no difference** in the prepared statement syntax. just use the same syntax for select that you used (and which really worked) for insert.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off, and `email_input` should instead be a positional parameter:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM emailstobeverified WHERE email = ? and verification_code = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $email_input, $code);
$stmt->execute();
```